# Visualizing split extensions and central extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, visualization

This may be a bit of a silly question, but I think it is useful to get a *visual* idea of the concept of group extensions. A short exact sequence $1 \to A \overset{i}{\to} B \overset{\pi}{\to} C \to 1$ can be diagrammatically represented as follows (where cosets of $A$ in $B$, represented by horizontal rows, get surjectively mapped to $C$; $A$ is mapped injectively into a horizontal row in $B$):

[image]

$B$ is basically the group that is generated using groups $A$ and $C$.

---

**Question 1**:

A **split extension** is defined as an extension $1 \to A \overset{i}{\to} B \overset{\pi}{\to} C \to 1$ with a homomorphism $s: B \to C$ such that going from $B$ to $C$ by $s$ and then back to $B$ by the quotient map of the short exact sequence induces the identity map on $C$, i.e., $\pi \circ s = \mathrm{id}_C$. In this case, $s$ is called a *section* and it "splits" the exact sequence.

For general groups $A$ and $C$, is $\mathrm{Im}(s)$ (the image of the homomorphism $s: C \to B$) necessarily a *vertical column* in the above diagram of $B$ or can it just be a set of one representative element from *each* horizontal row?

---

**Question 2**:

A **central extension** is one where $A$ lies in $Z(B)$. And let's consider only non-split central extensions so as to exclude direct products. In such a case, can we say anything specific about how $\mathrm{Im}(s)$ might look like in the above diagram? Like, certainly $\mathrm{Im}(s)$ can *not* be a vertical column, unlike in the case of split extensions(?). But can $\mathrm{Im}(s)$ only be a horizontal row in $B$?

---

**P.S**: I took the diagram from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXEiJhBHJsU&list=PLL0ATV5XYF8AQZuEYPnVwpiFy0jEipqN-&index=49).

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is very on point, because it highlights the issue with this diagram: the rectangular shape only makes sense for a split extension to begin with.

For a general extension, what makes sense is that you can divide $B$ in $A$-cosets, and that each coset corresponds to an element of $C$. But the rectangular shape says more than that: it implies that there are columns, that is it implies that there is a natural correspondence between certain elements of each coset. Precisely, there is one row which is completely understood: the one in purple, corresponding to the trivial coset $A$ (the one corresponding to the trivial element of $C$). If you draw a rectangle, then in each row (coset) you have an element "in the same column" as some $a\in A$. This means that you actually have an explicit decomposition (at least setwise ) $B\simeq A\times C$.

But to do that basically amounts to choosing a section, which is only possible when the extension is split. So not only columns don't really make sense when the extension is not split, those columns should actually be *defined* by a section. So to answer your question: yes, a section should land in a column, *by definition of what a column should be*.

Of course you can also say that for any extension you can always choose a set-theoretic decomposition $B\simeq A\times C$, and draw your rectangle that way. But this means that the diagram basically ignores the algebraic data (or at least partially: the rows still make sense, but the columns don't). This is a pretty bad idea in my opinion. In this case, a section need not correspond to a column because columns are completely arbitrary and don't make algebraic sense.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really clear for me why all elements of the image of a section $s$ necessarily land on the *same* column. Could you please explain? Is it to preserve the homomorphism property of $s$?

Comment: Like, why can't half of the elements of $C$ land on the column corresponding to some $a_i$ while the other half lands on the column corresponding to some $a_j$ where $a_i, a_j \in A$?

Comment: I'm not sure you got the point of my answer. What I am saying is that the only reasonable way to *define* what a column is is to say: let $s:C\to B$ be a section; then a column is *by definition* the translation by some element of $A$ of the image of $s$. If you choose a different section, it changes the definition of what a column is, so that the image of this new section is again a column with this new definition. Before you choose a section, there is no reasonable way to define what a column is.